# Extracting Open Triangles in R Igraph (Network Analysis)

Tags: r, igraph

I have an edge list where I want to extract the **open** triangles meaning that if: A knows B and B knows C, but C's relationship with A isn't captured in the graph.

Is there a way to extract this is in R? I know you can do it with plain triangles but I wanted to know if you can extract open triangles.

I have created a network graph in R with an edge list that looks as follows:

```
structure(list(ego = c(323L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 
174L, 174L, 174L, 428L, 428L, 428L, 428L, 428L, 428L, 428L, 428L, 
364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 422L, 422L, 422L, 
422L, 422L, 422L, 422L, 422L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 
329L, 329L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 330L, 330L, 
330L, 330L, 330L, 330L, 330L, 330L, 415L, 428L), alter = c(174L, 
323L, 428L, 364L, 422L, 329L, 31L, 330L, 415L, 392L, 174L, 364L, 
422L, 329L, 31L, 330L, 415L, 392L, 174L, 428L, 422L, 329L, 31L, 
330L, 415L, 392L, 174L, 428L, 364L, 329L, 31L, 330L, 415L, 392L, 
174L, 428L, 364L, 422L, 31L, 330L, 415L, 392L, 174L, 428L, 364L, 
422L, 329L, 330L, 415L, 392L, 174L, 428L, 364L, 422L, 329L, 31L, 
415L, 392L, 174L, 323L), advice_tie = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ego", "alter", "advice_tie"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -60L))
```

I created the network graph as follows in R:

```
edges2 <- graph.data.frame(edges)

edges3 <- as.undirected(edges2, mode='collapse')
summary(edges3)

plot(edges3)
edges
```

This is what edges3 looks like after going becoming undirected:

```
IGRAPH UN-- 10 37 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):
 [1] 323--174 323--428 174--428 174--364 428--364
 [6] 174--422 428--422 364--422 174--329 428--329
 [11] 364--329 422--329 174--31  428--31  364--31 
 [16] 422--31  329--31  174--330 428--330 364--330
 [21] 422--330 329--330 31 --330 174--415 428--415
 [26] 364--415 422--415 329--415 31 --415 330--415
 [31] 174--392 428--392 364--392 422--392 329--392
 [36] 31 --392 330--392
```

Desired Output (because 323 and 392 are the only ones in this case that do not connect to everything else besides to 428):

```
415  174 323
31   174 323
422  174 323
329  174 323
364  174 323
392  174 323
330  174 323
31   415 392
422  415 392
329  415 392
364  415 392
392  415 392
330  415 392
428  415 392
174  415 392
```

[image]

I hope this makes sense! Thanks

Comment: If I copy your `edges` data and transform as you do, the `edges3` doesn't look like your result. Did you paste the full version of your edges? or you used `head`?

Comment: Paste the `dput` result of your `edges` object would be the best.

Comment: @Psidom just changed it to make it easier to reproduce. Thanks!

Comment: You can also paste the desired output from the question you asked before here so that we can compare.

Comment: @Psidom thanks for the feedback. Changed the data a bit to make more sense out of it. Does this concept make sense to you?

Comment: It makes sense. But notice that for example, 392 is not connected to 415 either, so your assumption *323 is the only one in this case that does not connect to everything else besides to 428* is not correct.

Comment: @Psidom Ok my bad, I missed that, thanks for pointing that out. That's why I need to come up with a script that can extract that info so I don't make that kind of mistake in the future.

Comment: @Psidom Made the change

Comment: Just made an answer.

Comment: Your output is not a complete set of open triangles. You can check the results below with the graph you plotted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we start from the edges given, firstly we construct an `igraph` object which we will call it `G` instead of `edges3` here because it is a *graph* not *edges*.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(edges)
G <- as.undirected(g, mode='collapse')
```

In order to find all the open triangles, we loop through all the **vertices** of the graph, which is what the `lapply(as_ids(V(G)), ..` is doing here in the first line, and find out all the neighbors and loop through them again, i.e. `lapply(as_ids(neighbors(G, v)), ..`.

We make a condition check on the fourth line to make sure the distance between the origin `v` and neighbor's neighbor is 2, thus guaranteeing that the triangle is open (not connected and also not `v` itself).

The result is going to be returned as an ordered vector, which helps us to remove duplicated open triangles later which is done by the `unique` function at the beginning of the first line.

```
openTriList <- unique(do.call(c, lapply(as_ids(V(G)), function(v) {
    do.call(c, lapply(as_ids(neighbors(G, v)), function(v1) {
        v2 <- as_ids(neighbors(G, v1))
        v2 <- v2[shortest.paths(G, v, v2) == 2]

        if(length(v2) != 0) {
            lapply(v2, function(vv2) { c(v, v1, vv2)[order(c(v, v1, vv2))] })
        } else { list() }
    }))
})))
```

This piece of code will return a list of open triangles, and you can convert it to a matrix by `do.call(rbind, openTriList)`, where each row represent a unique open triangle:

```
> do.call(rbind, openTriList)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
 [1,] "174" "323" "364"
 [2,] "174" "323" "422"
 [3,] "174" "323" "329"
 [4,] "174" "31"  "323"
 [5,] "174" "323" "330"
 [6,] "174" "323" "415"
 [7,] "174" "323" "392"
 [8,] "323" "364" "428"
 [9,] "323" "422" "428"
[10,] "323" "329" "428"
[11,] "31"  "323" "428"
[12,] "323" "330" "428"
[13,] "323" "415" "428"
[14,] "323" "392" "428"
[15,] "174" "392" "415"
[16,] "392" "415" "428"
[17,] "364" "392" "415"
[18,] "392" "415" "422"
[19,] "329" "392" "415"
[20,] "31"  "392" "415"
[21,] "330" "392" "415"
```

Comment: I'm glad it helps!

Comment: Is there a way to extract just the open edges? It is tough to determine which one out of this list is the open edge

Comment: You can change the 7th line from `lapply(v2, function(vv2) { c(v, v1, vv2)[order(c(v, v1, vv2))] })` to `lapply(v2, function(vv2) c(v, v1, vv2))`. Thus you will always know that the first column and the last column will be open edges. But in this way, you will have duplicated records in the result. i.e. an open triangle can appear more than one time.