# Count occurrence of nodes in vertex of open triangles using igraph in R

Tags: r, performance, networking, igraph

In a network of passes among basketball players I want to:

1. **Detect open triangles in the network**
2. **Count the number of unique players in brokering position** (A passes to B & C; B & C don't pass to each other; A is brokering)
3. **Count the number of times these player broker an open triangle**

Following this question [Extracting Open Triangles in R Igraph (Network Analysis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370061/extracting-open-triangles-in-r-igraph-network-analysis) we can do the following:

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)
G <- sample_gnm(10, 15)

G
IGRAPH 72f8e6a U--- 10 15 -- Erdos renyi (gnm) graph
+ attr: name (g/c), type (g/c), loops (g/l), m (g/n)
+ edges from 72f8e6a:
[1] 1-- 3 1-- 4 3-- 4 1-- 5 3-- 5 6-- 7 3-- 8 4-- 8 6-- 8 7-- 8 2-- 9 6-- 9 7-- 9 4--10 9--10
 
plot(G)
```

[image: G]

Find the open triangles:

```
openTriList <- unique(do.call(c, lapply(as_ids(V(G)), function(v) {
    do.call(c, lapply(as_ids(neighbors(G, v)), function(v1) {
    v2 <- as_ids(neighbors(G, v1))
    v2 <- v2[shortest.paths(G, v, v2) == 2]

    if(length(v2) != 0) {
        lapply(v2, function(vv2) { c(v, v1, vv2)[order(c(v, v1, vv2))] })
    } else { list() }
    }))
})))
```

The results are correct:

```
do.call(rbind, openTriList)
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]    1    3    8
  [2,]    1    4    8
  [3,]    1    4   10
  [4,]    2    6    9
  [5,]    2    7    9
  [6,]    2    9   10
  [7,]    3    4   10
  [8,]    3    6    8
  [9,]    3    7    8
  [10,]    1    4    5
  [11,]    3    4    5
  [12,]    4    6    8
  [13,]    4    7    8
  [14,]    4    9   10
  [15,]    3    5    8
  [16,]    6    9   10
  [17,]    7    9   10
  [18,]    4    8   10
  [19,]    6    8    9
  [20,]    7    8    9
```

**How do we find the players that are brokers?**

- Player 2 is in this list because it is part of an open triangle, but is not a broker. We ignore this player.

**And how can we efficiently count the number of times these player broker an open triangle?**

- Player 9 is brokering 5 open triangles.

*[The real data holds millions of passes and several thousands of players. So performance is an important aspect. Using `combn` results in extremely long computational times. Are there faster ways of doing this? Perhaps getting the adjacency graph to build a sparse matrix and converting it into a `data.table` object for joining by neighbours? See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788471/can-we-find-the-neighbors-of-all-vertices-in-a-graph-without-a-loop-using-r). ]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

If you want to speed up, below is an option using `for` loops + `combn` to define a user functions `f`, which ouput a list including both the `openTriList` and `occurCnt` (*thank @minem's feedback as well for performance improvement*):

```
f <- function(G) {
  dmat <- as_adj(G, sparse = FALSE)
  resLst <- c()
  for (broker in 1:nrow(dmat)) {
    k <- which(dmat[broker, ] == 1)
    if (length(k) > 1) {
      inds <- t(combn(k, 2))
      resLst[[broker]] <- subset(cbind(broker, inds), dmat[inds] == 0)
    }
  }
  resLst <- do.call(rbind, resLst)
  resCnt <- table(resLst[, "broker"])
  list(openTriLst = resLst, occurCnt = resCnt)
}
```

and you will see that they can achieve the desired output

```
> set.seed(1234)

> G <- sample_gnm(10, 15)

> f(G)
$openTriLst
      broker
 [1,]      1 4  5
 [2,]      3 1  8
 [3,]      3 4  5
 [4,]      3 5  8
 [5,]      4 1  8
 [6,]      4 1 10
 [7,]      4 3 10
 [8,]      4 8 10
 [9,]      6 8  9
[10,]      7 8  9
[11,]      8 3  6
[12,]      8 3  7
[13,]      8 4  6
[14,]      8 4  7
[15,]      9 2  6
[16,]      9 2  7
[17,]      9 2 10
[18,]      9 6 10
[19,]      9 7 10
[20,]     10 4  9

$occurCnt

 1  3  4  6  7  8  9 10
 1  3  4  1  1  4  5  1
```

and the speed is remarkably improved than my previous answer. You can also compare it with the [answer by @minem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67090154/12158757).

```
> set.seed(1234)

> G1 <- sample_gnm(1000, 4000)

> system.time(f(G1))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.07    0.00    0.08

> G2 <- sample_gnm(10000, 40000)

> system.time(f(G2))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.46    0.16    2.62
```

---

## Previous Answer

You can try the code below using `combn` + `are_ajdacent`, e.g.,

```
G <- sample_gnm(10, 15) %>%
  get.data.frame() %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE)

openTriList <- do.call(
  rbind,
  sapply(
    names(V(G)),
    function(v) {
      nbs <- names(neighbors(G, v))
      if (length(nbs) > 1) {
        do.call(rbind, Filter(length, combn(nbs, 2, FUN = function(x) {
          if (!are_adjacent(G, x[1], x[2])) {
            sort(as.numeric(c(v, x)))
          }
        }, simplify = FALSE)))
      }
    }
  )
)

occurCount <- na.omit(
  sapply(names(V(G)), function(v) {
    nbs <- names(neighbors(G, v))
    ifelse(length(nbs) > 1,
      sum(!combn(nbs,
        2,
        FUN = function(x) are_adjacent(G, x[1], x[2])
      )),
      NA
    )
  })
)
```

and you will get named vector

```
> openTriList
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    4    5
 [2,]    1    3    8
 [3,]    3    4    5
 [4,]    3    5    8
 [5,]    6    8    9
 [6,]    1    4    8
 [7,]    1    4   10
 [8,]    3    4   10
 [9,]    4    8   10
[10,]    7    8    9
[11,]    2    6    9
[12,]    6    9   10
[13,]    2    7    9
[14,]    7    9   10
[15,]    2    9   10
[16,]    3    6    8
[17,]    3    7    8
[18,]    4    6    8
[19,]    4    7    8
[20,]    4    9   10

> occurCount
 1  3  6  4  7  9  5  8 10 
 1  3  1  4  1  5  0  4  1
attr(,"na.action")
2
6
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

Comment: This works great, but the `combn` function is slowing it down. The computation I need to do is estimated to take 500 hours. Is there a possible work-around?

Comment: @wake_wake I guess the computational complexity is `O(n^3)` given `n` vertices in your network. In that case, if you have millions of vertices, it is inevitably heavy and spending a lot of time.

Comment: I see. I've now removed the answered mark and assigned a bounty to solicit an efficient approach. If there is none, I reinstate your answer. Thank you, Thomas!

Comment: @chinsoon12 is joining on neighbors an option here?

Comment: @wake_wake Please check out my update, which improves the performance if we resort to the `for` loop + `combn` method.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding See updated code for `fun_openTriList`. Should be much faster with only small code changes. I think you where growing object in: `res <- rbind(res, do.call(rbind, r))`

Comment: @minem Yes, exactly! Thanks for you contribution!

Answer (score 2):

I reworked `openTriList` calculation by Thomas:

```
require(data.table)

v2 <- function(a) {
  n <- names(V(a))
  d <- as.data.table(a %>% get.data.frame())
  d <- as.data.table(lapply(d, as.numeric))
  k1 <- d[[1]]
  k2 <- d[[2]]
  ks <- k1 + k2
  # v <- n[[1]] # for testing
  xx <- sapply(n, function(v) {
    nbs <- as.numeric(names(neighbors(a, v)))
    vn <- as.numeric(v)
    
    if (length(nbs) > 1) {
      i2 <- combn(nbs, 2, simplify = F)
      
      # reduce test vectors:
      ss <- sapply(i2, sum)
      ii <- ks %in% ss
      kk1 <- k1[ii]
      kk2 <- k2[ii]
      
      # reduce test vectors 2:
      i <- (kk1 %in% nbs) & (kk2 %in% nbs)
      kk1 <- kk1[i]
      kk2 <- kk2[i]
      
      # x <- i2[[1]] # for testing
      i3 <- lapply(i2, function(x) {
        q1 <- kk1 == x[1]
        q2 <- kk2 == x[2]
        zz <- q1 & q2
        r2 <- !any(zz)
        if (is.null(r2) || r2) {
          rs <- c(vn, x)
          rs <- .Internal(sort(rs, decreasing = F)) # less overhead
          rs
        }
      })
      s <- i3[lengths(i3) > 0]
      do.call(rbind, s)
      }
    }
  )
  do.call(rbind, xx)
}

openTriList <- v2(G)
```

This should be significantly faster. `combn` isnt slow. Slow is `are_adjacent`.
Thomas code is written quite complicated, its hard to debug and find possible slowdowns...
Test:

```
set.seed(1)
G <- sample_gnm(1000, 4000)
G <- get.data.frame(G) %>% graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE)
system.time(r1 <- v1(G)) # 12.00 sec
system.time(r2 <- v2(G)) # 0.99 sec
all.equal(r1, r2) # TRUE
```

### Update

```
fun_openTriList2 <- function(G) {
  dmat <- as_adj(G, sparse = FALSE)
  res <- list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(dmat)) {
    inds <- which(dmat[i, ] == 1)
    if (length(inds) > 1) {
      r <- combn(inds, 2,
                 FUN = function(x) {
                   if (dmat[x[1], x[2]] == 0) {
                     .Internal(sort(c(i, x), decreasing = F))
                   }
                 },
                 simplify = F
      )
      res[[i]] <- do.call(rbind, r)
    }
  }
  res <- do.call(rbind, res)
  res
}
```

Comment: Nice point to figure out that `are_adjacent` is the bottleneck. Upvoted your answer! You can see my update regarding the speed improvement.